# document.currentScript.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML doesn't work in ajax call

Tags: javascript, insertadjacenthtml

We have a component that contains the following script block to insert a js observable image that gets updated when it comes into view:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.currentScript.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<span class="js-dom-observable js-dom-observable--picture"><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" data-src="http://www.fillmurray.com/500/500" alt="Image"></span>');
</script>
```

This works well when the component is loaded directly onto the page, however, when it is in the html as a result of an ajax call and appended to the page, it no longer adds the image - I'm guessing it's because the `document.currentScript` is no longer the script tag it is in but the script that is executing the ajax:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: `/${APP_NAME}${filterResultEndpoint}`,
  type: 'POST',
  traditional: true,
  data: searchData.getPostData(),
  success: result => {
    $('.results').html(result);
  },
});
```

Is there a way to make this `insertAdjacentHTML` in the script tag work in an ajax call - if I replace the `insertAdjacentHTML` with a simple `document.write`, it will work in both cases, but I'm unable to use that as it will fail our coding analysis policies

Answer (score 0):

[document.currentScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) is a global variable that changes durning parsing of all the script tags

it becomes null after the DOM have been parsed.

You have to store the element to a variable before making any asynchronous operations

```
var element = document.currentScript
$.ajax({
  success() {
    element.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML(...)
  }
})
```

Comment: hmm, if there are multiple script tags been parsed in the ajax result, how would I handle that?

Comment: `document.currentScript` can only be one at the time and it will always be the script tag that currently being processed